# Google Maps geocoder unable to assign result

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Geocoder is working fine, but i can't seem to use result.

```
 var naddress;
 var ngc = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 ngc.geocode({'latLng': nll}, function(results, status) {
 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
   if (results[0]) {
    alert(results[0].formatted_address);
    naddress = results[0].formatted_address;
    }
   }
 });
alert(naddress);
```

It show me the correct address at first alert(), but second is blank.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What happens if you put the first alert AFTER the assignment?  And how do you know which alert is which?

Comment: Same result. Is it anything to do, that this part of code is inside ajax requests callback function? It seemed to work outside ajax callback.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee in which order the function passed to `geocode` and the first statement after the call to `geocode` will execute.  So you either have to check to see if `naddress` has been assigned to yet, or put the code that needs it in the callback function.